# Opening a single MIDI input stream from multiple applications simultaneously

Tags: windows, midi, winmm

We are adding support for accessing various MIDI controller devices within our application. From our own trials using `midiInOpen`, it seems that only one application can access a MIDI input device using `midiInOpen`.  The second application that attempts to open the MIDI device fails with an error `MMSYSERR_NOMEM`.

However, I have an example of a commercial application (3rd party) which manages to access a MIDI input stream at the same time as our application (which uses `midiInOpen`).  This suggests that there is another way of accessing the MIDI stream.

I used an API sniffer to see the API calls, and this application doesn't use `midiInOpen`.  It uses `midiInMessage` and `midiOutMessage`, and from the API docs, these appear to be communicating directly with the driver.

I see from documentation that new support for MIDI is provided in Windows 10; I haven't experimented yet with how it works alongside an app that uses `midiInOpen`, but if possible, I need to find a solution which works with Windows 7 and above.

I have contacted the third party app developer to see if they can help.  Currently. our app works alongside their app, but there are other apps that use `midiInOpen` to access MIDI data, and our app cannot co-exist with theirs.  The first app that calls `midiInOpen` gets the MIDI stream; the second call fails.

All this testing has been done with Windows 7.  We need to support 7 and above.

Our mac version of the application works fine in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Some devices have non-standard WinMM drivers with multi-client support. But this is obviously not the case here.

Currently, Microsoft provides three MIDI APIs in Windows:

- the [WinMM MIDI functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742875(v=vs.85).aspx) (`midiInOpen` etc.),
- the [DirectMusic API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/audio/midi-and-directmusic-components), and
- the [Windows 10 UWP MIDI API](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/21/midi-enhancements-in-windows-10/).

Apparently, that 3<sup>rd</sup>-party application uses DirectMusic.